# Can I export from a query in access to a text file without wrapping strings in quotes

Tags: ms-access, text-files, export-to-csv

I'm trying to do an export from access into a text file via a query

```
select CustomerName
into [Text;FMT=TabDelimited;HDR=NO;DATABASE=C:\Temp\;].CustomerList.txt 
from Customer
```

however, every line is getting wrapped in double quotes. Is there a way to turn off the quoting (I'm only ever setting one column), or can I use a custom quote character (e.g. set it to blank)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

You have to add manually a [schema.ini](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx) in the directory you wish to export

In your case, it should contain :

```
TextDelimiter="none"
```

---

### Method 2

Another way to do it is to use the [TransferText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141567%28v=office.10%29.aspx), with :

> SpecificationName  Optional Variant. A string expression that's the
>   name of an import or export specification you've created and saved in
>   the current database. For a fixed-width text file, you must either
>   specify an argument or use a schema.ini file, which must be stored in
>   the same folder as the imported, linked, or exported text file. To
>   create a schema file, you can use the text import/export wizard to
>   create the file. For delimited text files and Microsoft Word mail
>   merge data files, you can leave this argument blank to select the
>   default import/export specifications.

for your export specification, which is a oneshot operation, you will use the wizard and there you have an "advanced" button bringing a menu where you can set the text delimiter to nothing.

---

Google is your friend. You've got enough clues now to sort it out.